# Python dict list of numpy ndarrays not updating in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to use dicts to hold different types of data. I want to use label_dict to hold information from plotting_dict. Plotting_dict currently has a key ‘Batched_total_traces’ which holds a numpy.ndarray of fluorescence data for several neurons over time, and another key “Batched_total_labels” which is a numpy.ndarray holding kmeans clustered labels ex. [3 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 0 2 1 3 0]. I want to create keys for each unique label (0, 1, 2, 3) and put the fluorescence time trials in the appropriate key.

```
def label_dict(plotting_dict):
    label_dict = {}
    counter = 0
    for label, trace in zip(plotting_dict['Batched_total_labels'], plotting_dict['Batched_total_traces']):
        if label not in label_dict.keys():
            label_dict[label] = trace
        else:
            label_dict[label] += trace
    
    print(counter)
    return label_dict
```

This is my most recent attempt, but the keys just seem to be a single time trial for a single neuron.

I have also tried list(trace) and .append(), but that gives me a different set of problems, where each key has too many values and the total number for all the keys is 790, where I should have 354.

Update:
I realized that `label_dict[label]` was just the first `trace` and was shape (110, ). I created an empty list instead and `trace` to that which has solved the issue. I don't understand why `label_dict[label]` was not updating though. This is the code I use to add to `label_dict[1]` for example and any insight as to why this works would be greatly appreciated.

```
def label_dict(plotting_dict):
    label_dict = {}
    for label, trace in zip(plotting_dict['Batched_total_labels'], plotting_dict['Batched_total_traces']):
        if label not in label_dict.keys():
            label_dict[label] = []
            label_dict[label].append(trace)
        else:
            label_dict[label].append(trace)
    return label_dict
```

Comment: Is the `zip` output correct?  Are the `Batched_total..` arrays one dimension?

Comment: ```zip``` outputs what I expect, and Batched_total_traces is 354 arrays each of the dimensions (110,) while Batched_total_labels is a list of length 354.